# how to configure jvm and eclipse in mac os 10.6

Tags: java, iphone, macos, jakarta-ee, plugins

Unable to locate the JVM for project GuestBook. Please verify that you have a project-level JVM installed by inspecting your project's build path.

Comment: How is the title related to the rest of the question?

Answer (score 2):

sounds like you imported a project from a different OS and had a JRE selected that isn't on MacOS.

On the menu, select Project->Properties.  On the left select Java Build Path and look at the bottom of the "Libraries" tab.  You'll see the JRE library.  Select that and click "Edit...".  In the next screen, change the JRE to either the workspace default JRE or select one from Alternate JRE.